Tag graph from stared.gihtub.io/tagoverflow
I just discovered the Tagoverflow Tool, and thought I'd share it with you.

The picture shows the 32 most used tags on Bitcoin.SE colored by community detection. The two orange ones that are partially on top of each other should read development and block.

How does it do community detection?

@NickODell: I would assume that "community detection" here means how often the tags are used together.
